# I got the problem in Crystal Report- Error Messsage:Load report failed

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, c#-3.0

I got the problem in Crystal Report- Error Messsage:Load report failed.

how to solve this issue??.

Comment: @ayps specify your error report in detail....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your report is running for awhile and then falls over make sure you Dispose it.......

```
if(myReport != null)
{
    myReport .Close();
    myReport .Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call show data on report in DataBinding and Navigate methods.

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowReportData();
}  

protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Navigate(object source,  CrystalDecisions.Web.NavigateEventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowReportData();
}
```